# Random coefficients in the polynom package?

Tags: random-numbers, polynom, probsoln

I am using the `probsoln` package to generate random math quizzes.  For polynomial division, I can generate random integer coefficients, but I had planned on using the `polynom` package to auto-generate the solution, but I keep getting one of those "I was expecting a number" errors.

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{polynom}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\begin{document}
  \random{myCounter}{1}{10}
  \[ \polylongdiv{ \value{myCounter}x^2 + 1 }{ x + 1 } \]
\end{document}
```

I have also tried this using `\arabic{myCounter}` instead of `\value`, and I have tried using `\pgfmathsetmacro{\newMacro}{\value{myCounter}` followed by `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\truncatedMacro}{\newMacro}`.  Each time, `\polylongdiv' issues the same error.

The .sty file:  I have even opened up the .sty file to try and understand how `\polylongdiv` works, but it just looked like my cats and my kids had randomly played with my keyboard.  I couldn't even begin to parse it.

Does anyone have a quick insight/adjustment I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should expand the number before `\polylongdiv` starts its work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{polynom}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\newcommand\epolylongdiv[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\polylongdiv{#1}{#2}}\x}

\begin{document}
  \random{myCounter}{1}{10}
  \[ \epolylongdiv{ \themyCounter x^2 + 1 }{ x + 1 } \]
  \random{myCounter}{1}{10}
  \[ \epolylongdiv{ \themyCounter x^2 + 1 }{ x + 1 } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked really well, thanks!  I was also able to adapt your suggestion to work with the `\polynomialfrac' command from the `polynomial' package.