# Is there a way to have LaTeX perform distribution?

Tags: math-mode

I tried to do a search for this as I have to imagine it's somewhere... but I couldn't find it (probably not using the right keywords or something)

Anyway, what I want is to be able to put in a set of factors, and have the command output the distributed result. I know the polynom package can do the reverse of this with polynomials, but I am hoping to distribute out the factors.

So for example, I would input something like (x^2-1)(x+2) and the output would be x^3+2x^2-x-2

Comment: Distribution? You mean mathematical expansion of the brackets?

Comment: Yes. Even just polynomial expansion would be sufficient, although a more flexible tool would be ideal. It's a common enough thing to do I would imagine there has to be a package somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Well, LaTeX is no Computer algebra system

Comment: True enough, however the Polynom package allows for taking polynomials  (with rational coefficients) and factoring them... which is a significantly harder computational problem. If it can do that, I would assume it could expand polynomials as it is much more straightforward.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I've not used that package so far

Comment: Don't expect it to work with non-integer numbers. TeX is not good at math.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `polynom` package has a low level function `\polyprint` which prints the expanded form of a polynomial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polyprint{(x^2-1)(x+2)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for!
As another quick question, is there a way to use counter numbers as the numbers? the \arabic doesn't seem to work, i.e. \polyprint{(x-\arabic{counter})(x+1)} doesn't compile for "counter" being a counter that is say 1.

Comment: @Jason You should ask a separate question.

Comment: @Jason To use counters as coefficients you will need to define a new `\eprintpoly` command as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81677/random-coefficients-in-the-polynom-package

Answer (score 10):

The `sagetex` [package](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf) has this feature for polynomials and more. You need Sage installed locally or, better yet, [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) to run (no installation needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x = var("x")
a = x+1
b = x^2-5*x+2
c = Integer(randint(2,7))*x^2-Integer(randint(2,7))*x+    Integer(randint(2,9))
# c is creating a random quadratic
d = sin(x)+2
e = 2^x+1
\end{sagesilent}
\noindent If we want to expand $(\sage{a})(\sage{b})$ the answer is 
$\sage{expand(a*b)}$. The expansion of $(\sage{b})(\sage{c})$
gives $\sage{b*c}$. Finally $(\sage{a})(\sage{b})(\sage{c})=\sage{expand(a*b*c)}$.

We can multiply out things which aren't polynomials, too:
\[(\sage{d})(\sage{e})=\sage{expand(d*e)}=\sage{simplify(expand(d*e))}\]
\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:[image]
The Sage documentation on expand() and simplify() is [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html#sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.expand).

Comment: This seems to be a very powerful tool... although at a quick glance Sage is something like 6GB to download, which might be a little rough on a chromebook which is where I do most of my LaTeX now adays. Might be worth looking into it more though, the online one seemed to run well, but this means I need to learn Sage.

Regardless, thanks.