# What are the available macros for algebra and calculus?

Tags: macros, packages, calculations, package-writing

The `polynom` package can provide all the steps of a long division of polynomials if I just provide the polynomials:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{x^4-3x^3-5x^2+x-4}{x-3}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Are there packages or macros for matrices as well? For example, after we input a matrix and compile, the document shows the inverse, or the steps to find the REF of an augmented matrix.

Are there packages or macros for vectors as well? Dot product, cross product, linear combinations.

Are there packages or macros for deriatves and integrals?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't such a package for matrices, however, there are several dedicated approaches from users: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112599/213149

Comment: Thank you @antshar I also just found this other source that is a good complement: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357978/81269

Comment: I don't think there is such a package. The [CTAN site](https://www.ctan.org/) is where you can search. The [sagetex package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) gives you access to an open source CAS (like Mathematica). So it can generate the answers but not the steps. See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251419/is-there-a-way-to-have-latex-perform-distribution/251445#251445) for polynomials or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477728/how-do-i-construct-an-nxn-matrix/477759#477759) for matrices. Search this site for more.